# Stuck with String.replace java with regex

Tags: java, regex

I have a simple code where i want to replace multiple commas in the string with a single comma. Here what i tried. I is finding a match also but somehow i cant replace it . I am clueless what i am doing wrong.

```
    String s = "stt,111,,,234";
    String pattern = "\\d[,]{2,}\\d";
    Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher m = r.matcher(s);
    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(0));
        String res = m.group(0);
        s = s.replace(res, ",");
        System.out.println("string after replacement=" + s);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Not found");
    }
    s = s.replace("\\d[,]{2,}\\d", ",");
    System.out.println("Another try string after replacement=" + s);
```

And here is result :

```
Found value: 1,,,2
s=stt,111,,,234
s==stt,111,,,234
```

Why can't I replace the string even when it is found. 
I am sure it is something small but just cant figure out what it is.
THanks

Comment: You can try something like **s.replaceAll("[,]{2,}", ",")**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just use replaceAll method of string class like as follow.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String s = "stt,111,,,234";
        System.out.println("--------"+s.replaceAll("[,]{2,}", ","));

    }
```

Comment: Great.. that worked but now another problem is that it it is removing the first and the last digit. How can i keep them? Now the result is coming              
    string after replacement=stt,11,34 But i want                                                                
    string after replacement=stt,111,234

Comment: Above code will give you result as **stt,111,234**, try it

Comment: Oh yes. Thats great!! Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

replaceAll method works quite well for your example..try this:

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    String str = "11,,,222,,,333,,,,,,4444,,,,,,,55555,,,555";
    str = str.replaceAll(",{2,}", ",");
    System.out.println(str);

}
```

Input:
"11,,,222,,,333,,,,,,4444,,,,,,,55555,,,555"
Output:
11,222,333,4444,55555,555

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code, it will work.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Abc
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String str = "abc,,,,,,,,xyz,,,,abc";
        str = str.replaceAll("(.)\\1+","$1");
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```